# Converting enum tostring of underlying type in VB.Net (Option Strict On)

Tags: vb.net, enums, option-strict

I'd like to get a string representation of the underlying type of the enum.

```
    Dim target As System.ConsoleColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
    Dim actual = 'What goes here?
    Dim expected = "11"
```

Comment: Not sure I understand: do you want the integer value backing ConsoleColor.Cyan, do you want the string "Cyan", or do you want the string "ConsoleColor.Cyan"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# terms; you could assume int:

```
int val = (int) target;
string valString = val.ToString();
```

or if you don't want the assumption:

```
object val = Convert.ChangeType(target,
    Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(ConsoleColor)));
string valString = val.ToString();
```

Comment: The results of your example are: valueName="ConsoleColor" and typeName="Cyan"